# Showing that and Poisson-distribution is LAN and finding the respective sequences

Tags: statistics, asymptotics

Could really use some help here:

I do net the property of the Poisson distribution being LAN for independent RVs drawn from said distribution. Furthermore I do need the sequences which guarantee (that is, can be deducted from the Poisson distribution being LAN) the property in the Taylor Expansion.

So I do need to show that:

$\mathbb{P}_{\lambda} = Poi\left( \lambda \right), \, \lambda > 0$, with n independent RVs, $\mathbb{P}_{n,\lambda} = \mathbb{P}^n_{\lambda}$ being the joint distribution. And I do have to show that $\mathbb{P}_{n,\lambda}$ is LAN for a $\lambda_0$ and furthermore I do have to calculate the sequences $\delta_n$ and $Z_{n,\lambda_0}$.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Edit: So this is what I do have so far.

The idea behind all of this is to find the Taylor-expansion of the likelihood function to show that this is, in fact LAN. We know that for a twice continuously differentiable likelihood function the experiment is LAN, but to obtain the sequences we have to calculate the LAN property.

With the density of a Poisson-distribution being: $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\exp(-\lambda)$, we do have for $n$ i.i.d. RVs the likelihood:

\begin{equation}
\ln p_{n,\lambda}\left(x_1,\dots ,x_n\right\vert \lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ 
 k_i \ln\left( \lambda \right) - \ln\left( k_i! \right) - \lambda \right]
\end{equation}

Thus, for the two derivatives

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d\ln p_{n,\lambda}}{d\lambda} &= \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{k_i}{\lambda}-1 \\
\dfrac{d^2 \ln p_{n,\lambda}}{d^2 \lambda} &= \sum_{i=1}^n -\dfrac{k_i}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}

Hence, for the Taylor-Expansion:

\begin{align}
ln \dfrac{p_{n,\lambda_0 + \delta\lambda_0}}{p_{n,\lambda_0}} &= \delta\lambda_0 \dfrac{d\ln p_{n,\lambda_0}}{d \lambda_0} + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \delta \lambda_0 \right)^2 \dfrac{d^2 \ln p_{n,\lambda_0}}{d^2 \lambda_0}
\\
&= \delta \lambda_0 \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{k_i}{\lambda_0} - 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \delta \lambda_0 \right)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n - \dfrac{k_i}{\lambda_0^2}
\end{align}

Now, choosing $\delta_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, the first is:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n k_i - \lambda_0
\end{equation}

And by the Central Limit Theorem this converges to a Normal distribution with variance being the fisher information. Remember: $\mathbb{E}X = \lambda$ if $\mathbb{P}X = Poi(\lambda)$.

But I do need to show that for this $\delta_n$ the second term in the expansion converges to the fisher information (thats what theory says, but I can not seem to find the solution for this).

Sorry, notation: $Z_{n,\lambda_0}$ would be the second part in the Taylor-Expansion.

Comment: What does LAN mean?

Comment: Local Asymptotic Normality